# Ligação ao localhost nao funciona webview Android

Tags: android

Se tento aceder diretamente ao localhost do servido atraves do Chrome consigo entrar mas atraves de uma aplicação fica a página em branco, segue o código:

```
public class WebActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webcontent);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.loadUrl("192.168.1.66/sir1415/teste/teste.html");


    }
```

Comment: Aparece algum erro no logcat na IDE? Chegou a tentar colocar o protocolo na url? e.g: `http://192.192.168.1.66/sir1415/teste/teste.html`. Acredito que o browser faça isso de forma transparente.

Comment: Não aparece nenhum erro e com essa configuração também não funciona

Comment: Tente usar `http://10.0.2.2/`. Este é um endereço IP especial para rotas que o emulador usa para localhost em sua máquina.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui descobrir a solução, quando se usa webview para localhost tem de se usar a porta, mesmo que no navegador NÃO precise no webview precisa sempre, ou seja  o endereço fica assim:
http://192.192.168.1.66:80/sir1415/teste/teste.html